# Scroll/position to bottom when new info appears in Divs (via CheckBox Selection)

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, autoscroll

I'm working on a page the asks the user to select from checkboxes, as they make their selections new info appears (based on the selected checkboxes). 
I'd like for the window to auto scroll as new info appears on the page.

I've research this online and could not find a solition that matches my coding.
This is an example of my code bellow. I tried to use variation of

```
element.scrollTop = element.clientHeight;
```

and

```
var $objDiv = $("#logtext");
```

$objDiv.scrollTop( $objDiv.height() );

```html
<html>
 
<head>
 
<script>
element.scrollTop = element.clientHeight;
</script>

 
<script> 
var $objDiv = $("#logtext");
$objDiv.scrollTop( $objDiv.height() );
</script>
 
</head>
<body>
 

 
<form method="post" action="#">
 
 
  <h4>Select a fruit:</h4>
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="choice-apple” id="choice-apple” required>
      <label for="choice-apple”>Apple</label>
 
      <div class="reveal-if-active">
        <label for=“apple”><p><font color="purple">"I'm glad to Hear that!<br>Why do you like apples?”</label><br></p>
        <input type="button" value=“more apples" onclick = "location.href=‘apple1.html'">
      </div>
    </div>
 
<p><font color="black">
    <div>
 
      <input type="checkbox" name="choice-banana” id="choice-banana”>
      <label for="choice-banana”>Banana</label>
 
      <div class="reveal-if-active">
    <label for="negative"><p><font color="red">"I'm surprised to hear that. Why do you like bananas?</label><br></p>
        <input type="Button" value=“more bananas“ onclick = "location.href=‘bananas1.html'">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
</form>
<br> 
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this $("#logtext").scrollTop($("#logtext")[0].scrollHeight);

Comment: Why have you put `element.scrollTop = element.clientHeight;` etc in your `<head>`?

Comment: @samnu pel I tried  $("#logtext").scrollTop($("#logtext")[0].scrollHeight); and it did not work. But thanks for the answer all the same.

Comment: @stybl I thought I was to place the code in the head so it can load first. I did previously try it in different places to no avail.

Comment: This code is *JavaScript*. It is not part of the HTML. You need to place it within a `<script></script>` tag. Otherwise it will not do anything.

Comment: @stybl I did have them in the proper <script> ...</script> tags. must of go cut out when I edited my post. But I did have it that way on my page and it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution. Not sure if it's the best but it works so I thought I'd post it incase anyone else is struggling with this issue.
Feel free to edit or add/remove.
The only Problem now is that I can't get it to stop during mouse movement.

```js
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function moveWin()
  {  
    window.scroll(0,10000);
    setTimeout('moveWin();',2000);
  }
  </script>
```

```html
<body onLoad="moveWin();">
```

I would like to have it scroll when they click the Checkbox, and I'd still like to have it stop when the mouse moves.